# как задать цвета выбранным датам в календаре android studio?

Tags: android, дата, календарь

как сделать календарь в Android studio, в котором можно менять цвет нескольких выбранных  дат следующим образом: пользователь нажимает на дату и появляется выбор двух цветов, далее, пользователь выбирает цвет для  даты и дата становится выбранного цвета?

Comment: Что из вышеупомянутого у вас не получается?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

1. Календарь можно реализовать с помощью одной из библиотек, например [Caldroid](https://github.com/roomorama/Caldroid) или [times-square](https://github.com/square/android-times-square), [обработчики нажатия](https://github.com/roomorama/Caldroid#allow-user-to-select-a-date-and-inform-listener) на дату там уже есть.
2. При нажатии показывать диалог с выбором.
3. [Закрашивать нужным цветом ячейку календаря](https://github.com/roomorama/Caldroid#custom-backgrounds-and-text-colors-for-different-dates). Например `setBackgroundDrawableForDate(Drawable drawable, Date date)`; 
   вызываете этот метод, передаете дату и `drawable`.

Comment: Спасибо. Помогло

Comment: как выглядит код обработчика например в Caldroid? не могу сообразить

Comment: 2. При нажатии показывать диалог с выбором.
3. Закрашивать нужным цветом ячейку календаря.     Как это выглядит в виде кода?

Comment: @Nick, обновил ответ

Answer (score 0):

Выбор цвета сможешь реализовать на `FragmentDialog`.